Why does Praat's pitch contour seem to not match what I'm hearing? And how do I alleviate this issue to use it in teaching pronunciation?
I teach phonology and pronunciation to ESL students.
I intend to use Praat as a tool for students to visualize pitch contour when studying word stress, focus words, and intonation in questions. Seeing as many students who struggle with this seem to not be audio learners, I imagine a visual representation will help them.
However, whenever I (NS) record utterances, the pitch contours plotted in Praat don't seem to align with what I'm hearing (the rules I'm teaching).
For example, unstressed determiners seem to randomly appear at a higher pitch (even though they generally are lower than) their accompanying noun.
Also, 'focus words' (the most stressed word in a phrase) don't actually appear to be the most stressed word, according to Pitch contour.
Any ideas?

The general answer to your question is that all three of the phenomena you mention (word stress, focus, question intonation) don't just involve pitch, but also other aspects of prosody, such as duration and intensity, and more segmental aspects such as vowel quality. You also seem to assume that there is a direct, 1-to-1 mapping between pitch and (what you call) stress / (what I am going to call) prominence. I'll tackle these aspects in turn.
Duration, intensity, vowel quality: In sentences like "A house is a good investment" or "The house is on fire", if the subject is pronounced [ə haʊs] or [ðə haʊs], the reduced vowels in the determiners, and almost certainly their relatively short duration and relatively low intensity (note: you can also measure those two in Praat), will all tell you the same thing: these determiners are unstressed. If there happens to be a stretch of higher pitch on the determiners than on the noun - and given that they are sentence-initial, this is not unlikely (see below on declination) - that alone will probably not be enough to create the percept of an accent on those determiners, in the face of the three other cues all saying "unstressed". Given their shortness, it is also likely that (a) pitch perception is impaired (I've seen and heard very short schwas that consisted of only three or four glottal cycles - that's at the edge of where you can even perceive pitch), (b) Praat's pitch tracking algorithm runs into trouble (although it's generally better than its reputation).
Pitch-prominence mapping: Take the sentence "The house is on fire" and put focus (or: the nuclear accent) on the subject. You want to inform someone that the house (and not something else) is on fire. You will get "The house is on fire": there will probably be a high and/or rising pitch movement on "house", followed by low, flat pitch on all of "is on fire". In this case, there really seems to be a direct mapping between high pitch and high perceived prominence.
But now take that sentence and turn it into a question. You have reason to believe that the house is on fire, but you want to doublecheck that it's really the house and not something else. You will again get "The house is on fire?", but now you will probably have low pitch on "house", followed by a rise to high, flat-ish pitch, followed by another small rise on "fire" (there are other ways to intone a question, but this one should be reasonably common). The focus of the sentence and its nuclear accent is nevertheless on "house". So here you have low pitch corresponding to high prominence, and high pitch in the stretch of the sentence that was all low in the statement. And the pitch movement on "fire" doesn't even seem to be an accent, but seems to always happen on the phrase-final syllable.
Another experiment you could try: record yourself saying (pseudo-)minimal pairs w.r.t. stress such as "record" [n] and "record" [v], but embed them in frame sentences like "I said x again" or "Did you say x again?". Besides differences in duration, intensity and vowel quality, you should see pitch movements that are anchored to the stressed syllables, but may well take different forms in statements and in questions.
Declination and (pre-)nuclear accents: This one is maybe a little bit complicated, but bear with me: in English statements, you have a general tendency for pitch contours to slope downwards, i.e. they start high and end low. Or, in another perspective, a tendency for successive high accents to be realized lower and lower the further you go in the utterance (this is called "downstep"). No matter which way you look at it, this means that later high accents can easily 'look' less prominent than earlier high accents, despite sounding more prominent.
Let's change our example one more time: I ask you "What's new?", and you answer "The house is on fire", with an accent on each of the bold words. Most native speakers of English will probably perceive the focus / nuclear accent of the utterance on "fire", simply by virtue of it being the final accent of the phrase - even if, because of declination or downstep, it is numerically less prominent than the initial accent on "house". Note that in the earlier examples, I used contrast to make sure that the nuclear accent is on "house", i.e. that it is the final accent of the phrase, to sidestep this issue. This is really just another instance of there being no direct mapping between (high) pitch and (high) prominence.
Further reading: This answer was a short trip through some of the basic assumptions of what has been called autosegmental-metrical phonology, while trying to avoid most of the more technical terminology. If you want a book-length trip through this kind of thing, Intonational Phonology by Bob Ladd is highly recommended. Unlike this answer, it doesn't focus exclusively on English, either.

Thanks so much for this answer. I may look into that book. I always considered declination, which is why I'm trying to look into ways to use an image editing software to modify the pitch contours to account for that. Still wondering what to do about my ultimate questionː How do I account for all these things and use praat as a teaching tool in a TESOL course
